# How to reset identity column in MS Access

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have a windows application connected with `MS Access 2007` database

It had more than 300 records in `Customer` Table.

I have deleted all records. but after inserting a new record `CustomerID` returns `301`; but I want to set it to `1`.

I tried the following query:

```
ALter Table Customer alter column CustomerID Counter(1,1)
```

but it doesn't work

How can I reset an identity column in MSAccess??

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

On the operational side, you can drop an readd the column.

On the strategic side, I think you should rethink the problem: If the **value** of an identity column, apart from being unique, matters to you, you might be heading in a dangerous direction: You should think of such a column as being completly without content, apart from being a way to uniquely address a row.

Answer (score 3):

If you really must reset the autonumber, and you should first consider @Eugene Rieck's answer, you can compact and repair the database, which is something you should be doing with a back-end database on a fairly regular basis, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://allenbrowne.com/func-ADOX.html#ResetSeed). The key is:

```
strSql = "ALTER TABLE [" & strTable & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & strAutoNum & "] COUNTER(" & lngNext & ", 1);"
```

Alternatively, just drop and recreate the table.